# Saving photos and documents outside the application path and deploy kubernetes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, file-upload

I have a spring boot project that saves employee photos and other documents in

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\employee"
```

and stores the file name on the Database. Then I run the respecting Tomcat 8.0 on port 8085.
So, my front end can easily access those photos and files by requesting on http://localhost:8085/employee/photosOrDocNameFromDb.
The problem is my client wants to deploy it by Kubernetes. So, I have idea about how to deploy the spring boot application on Kubernetes, but how about those images and documents I save on the local file system?
Clearly, if I save my images inside the pods, I can't access it like the previous way(running a dummy tomcat to expose it by URL).
Is there any way that my Kubernetes deployed spring boot application can access the local file system? So that I can just run another tomcat on that location to access those images and documents.
Any Idea about how I can solve this. Should I use another pods to save those images? That case I have to access another pod fily system from the pod I deployed my application.

Answer (score 1):

You could user Persistent Volumes for that.

> **Types of Persistent Volumes**
>
> PersistentVolume types are implemented as plugins. Kubernetes currently supports the following plugins:
>
> awsElasticBlockStore - AWS Elastic Block Store (EBS)
> azureDisk - Azure Disk
> azureFile - Azure File
> cephfs - CephFS volume
> csi - Container Storage Interface (CSI)
> fc - Fibre Channel (FC) storage
> gcePersistentDisk - GCE Persistent Disk
> glusterfs - Glusterfs volume
> hostPath - HostPath volume (for single node testing only; WILL NOT WORK in a
> multi-node cluster; consider using local volume instead)
> iscsi - iSCSI (SCSI over IP) storage
> local - local storage devices mounted on nodes.
> nfs - Network File System (NFS) storage
> portworxVolume - Portworx volume
> rbd - Rados Block Device (RBD) volume
> vsphereVolume - vSphere VMDK volume

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/ for more details.